# How to calculate distance between two person using python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, euclidean-distance

I am working on a project where I have to calculate the distance between the detected persons in live video feed. To do this I am following the below pipeline:

```
1. Detect person using MobilenetSSD Caffe model
2. Extract bouding box of the persons detected
3. Calculate the centroid of each bouding box
4. Calculate the distance between the each centroid
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
for (id1, p1), (id2, p2) in combinations(centroid_dict.items(), 2):
    ec_dist = dist.euclidean((p1[0], p1[1]), (p2[0], p2[1]))
    print("Euclidean distance {}".format(ec_dist))
```

In above code `id1` and `id2` are the id of the two persons. `p1[0]` and `p1[1]` are the `x` and `y` coordinate of person 1 and `p2[0]` `p2[1]` are the `x` `y` coordinate of person2. I am calculating the `euclidean` distance between the `x` and `y` coordinates of both the person.

Now lets say two persons are standing at a distance of 2meter to each other, for this I am getting euclidean distance in the code as `250`. Now lets say if those two persons are now standing a bit far from the camera but the distance between them is still 2meter, in this case, I am getting euclidean distance as 343, which means the distance between person in the code is increasing if they are a bit far from the camera.

Initially I thought this logic will work fine regardless of where the persons are in the frame but looks like it is not working. Can anyone please help me suggest some good working solutions for this. Please help. Thanks

Comment: That is because an image / video is a 2D projection of a 3D world. In order to get the *actual* distance in meters you need an understanding of how far the people are from the camera. As long as you don't have that, all you can calculate is the appearent distance in pixel, which is what you have at the moment.

Comment: @mapf which means I also need to calculate the distance between the persons and the camera.? Do you have any links to article for this please.?

Comment: That's what it means, it's highly non-trivial though. I just had a look and found [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/depth-estimation-on-camera-images-using-densenets-ac454caa893).

Comment: There are to many variables because of the 2d projection as mafp mentioned. To make a calculation you should know the actual position in the 3d world. That would be their feet on the ground. If these are visible and you could create a grid, 1mx1m for example,  on the picture ground then you could calculate the distance.

Comment: @Mace Got it. So you mean I need to know the dimensions and the area of my ROI and then it will be accurate

Comment: It's really not that simple because among other things, you need to take perspective into account. It certainly won't be accurate, but it will be closer to the truth.

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to the question in your comment.

[image]

In a camera view you have 3d shortening. And the only thing that you can be certain of with a persons position in the view is their feet on the ground.

If you take in account the 3d shortening and draw a grid on the view you could make a good estimate of the distance by recalculating the grid and positions to square.